# Iframe youtube api video event setup

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there an event on videoId change?

I'm using a loadVideoById() function and I want to make an event when that happens.

```
$('div.search-box a').on('click', function(){
   sessionStorage.clear();
   sessionStorage.setItem('key', $(this).data("id"));
   player.loadVideoById({
   "videoId": $(this).data("id")              
});
```

**UPDATE**
this is what happenes after the code above:

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

videoID = sessionStorage.getItem("key");

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
    console.log("ucito api");
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: videoID,
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onApiChange': onPlayerApiChange
        }
    });
}
```

also you should know that onYoutubeIframeAPIReady() will put iframe inside

**UPDATE2**

```
var videoID;
var videoTitle;
var channelID;
var imgURL;
var viewsCount;
var newVideoId;

function newYoutubePlayer() {
    //Declare selectors
    var queryContainer = $('div.search-box ul');
    var searchBox = $('div#search-bar input[type=search]');

    //Declare variables from input elements :)
    var search = $(searchBox).val();
    var checker = search.length;

    //Check if the input is empty string
    if(search!=''){
        //Declare the YoutubeAPI link with youtube APIkey
        var theAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="+search+"&maxResults=15&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";

        //Get JSON string from YoutubeAPI link
        $.getJSON(theAPI, function(data){

            //Append 5 titles to the div
            for(var i=0; i<=5; ++i){

                //Using the kind property from YoutubeAPI determine is it a profile or video
                if(data.items[i].id.kind === 'youtube#video'){
                    $(queryContainer).append('<li><p><a href="#" data-name="'+data.items[i].snippet.title+'" data-id="' +data.items[i].id.videoId+'">' +data.items[i].snippet.title+'</a></p></li>');
                }else if(data.items[i].id.kind === 'youtube#channel'){
                    $(queryContainer).append('<li><p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/'+data.items[i].snippet.title+'">' +data.items[i].snippet.title+'</a></p></li>')
                }
            }

            $('div.search-box a').on('click', function(){
                newVideoId = $(this).data("id");
                sessionStorage.setItem('id', newVideoId);
                player.loadVideoById({
                    "videoId": newVideoId
                });


                // THIS IS FOR GETTING THE VIEWS NUMBER
                    var viewsAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id="+newVideoId+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(viewsAPI, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava broj pregleda");
                        viewsCount = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                        $('div#views').empty();
                        $('div#views').append('<p><span data-icon="&#xe087;"></span> '+viewsCount+'</p>');
                    });


                    //THIS IS FOR GETTING THE AUTHORS IMAGE
                    var channelAPi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id="+newVideoId+"+&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(channelAPi, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava id kanala");
                        channelID = data.items[0].snippet.channelId;

                        var imgAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id="+channelID+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                            $.getJSON(imgAPI, function(data){
                                console.log("ucitava sliku kanala");
                                imgURL = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                                $('div#user-icon').empty();
                                $('div#user-icon').append('<img class="user-image" src="'+imgURL+'"></img>');
                            });
                        });
            });           

            var tag = document.createElement('script');

            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            var sessionVideoID = sessionStorage.getItem('id');
            function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
                console.log("ucito api");
                player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '315',
                    width: '560',
                    videoId: sessionVideoId,
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });

                // THIS IS FOR GETTING THE VIEWS NUMBER
                    var viewsAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id="+newVideoId+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(viewsAPI, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava broj pregleda");
                        viewsCount = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                        $('div#views').empty();
                        $('div#views').append('<p><span data-icon="&#xe087;"></span> '+viewsCount+'</p>');
                    });


                    //THIS IS FOR GETTING THE AUTHORS IMAGE
                    var channelAPi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id="+newVideoId+"+&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(channelAPi, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava id kanala");
                        channelID = data.items[0].snippet.channelId;

                        var imgAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id="+channelID+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                            $.getJSON(imgAPI, function(data){
                                console.log("ucitava sliku kanala");
                                imgURL = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                                $('div#user-icon').empty();
                                $('div#user-icon').append('<img class="user-image" src="'+imgURL+'"></img>');
                            });
                        });
            }

            //The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            function onPlayerStateChange( event ) {

                if (  event.target.getVideoData().video_id == newVideoId ) {

                    // THIS IS FOR GETTING THE VIEWS NUMBER
                    var viewsAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id="+newVideoId+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(viewsAPI, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava broj pregleda");
                        viewsCount = data.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
                        $('div#views').empty();
                        $('div#views').append('<p><span data-icon="&#xe087;"></span> '+viewsCount+'</p>');
                    });


                    //THIS IS FOR GETTING THE AUTHORS IMAGE
                    var channelAPi = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id="+newVideoId+"+&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                    $.getJSON(channelAPi, function(data){
                        console.log("ucitava id kanala");
                        channelID = data.items[0].snippet.channelId;

                        var imgAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id="+channelID+"&key=AIzaSyA9ej5NSrEqzex76U_xE3PPJlb2rELrW9M";
                            $.getJSON(imgAPI, function(data){
                                console.log("ucitava sliku kanala");
                                imgURL = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

                                $('div#user-icon').empty();
                                $('div#user-icon').append('<img class="user-image" src="'+imgURL+'"></img>');
                            });
                        });

              }

                if (player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
                    // THIS IS FOR GETTING THE VIDEO TITLE
                    $('div#title').empty();
                    $('div#title').append('<p>'+ player.getVideoData().title+'</p>');

                     //THIS IS FOR GETTING THE AUTHORS NAME
                    $('p.user').empty();
                    $('p.user').append('<a href="#">'+player.getVideoData().author+'</a>');
                }

            }

        });

        //Check if the input value is changing, if it does cleares the previous output
        if(checker){
            $(queryContainer).empty();
        }

    }else{
        $(queryContainer).empty();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `iframe` is used for loading the videos. If you change the `videoId` then I think the `src` attribute of iframe is changed. If that's the case, then you can bind an event on iframe which will trigger every time the src is changed and hence it will be one of the solution to your problem:

```
$('#iframeid').load(function(){
    alert('videoID changed');
    //Your code logic here.
});
```

In case, you are not using jQuery, you can use equivalent event for Javascript. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand your selector. '#iframeid' ?? have you meant $('iframe')

Comment: It's an ID selector in jQuery.

Comment: I'll give it a try but on first look this has no sense O.o

Answer (score 0):

Everytime Youtube player changes it's state and you can add an event listener whilst you instantiate player.

Adding event listener

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '<VIDEO ID>',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange // adding event listener here 
    }
  });
}
```

This will call function `onPlayerStateChange`

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
     console.log( "New video change" );
}
```

Using `loadVideoById` and keeping watch on `onPlayerStateChange` method param `event.target`. Updated code as per your requirements.

```
// this code of yours will call my onPlayerStateChange function.
var newVideoId = $(this).data("id");
$('div.search-box a').on('click', function(){
   sessionStorage.clear();
   sessionStorage.setItem('key', $(this).data("id"));
   player.loadVideoById({
   "videoId": newVideoId              
   });
});

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (  event.target.getVideoData().video_id == newVideoId ) {
    console.log("new video loaded")
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried your method but It keeps late by one video. So when I click on the link and when everything happened this keeps the track of the last video, not the current one. I update my code up there so you can see.